# What's wrong with my code about swapping adjacent characters?

Tags: java

The question: Write a method called swapPairs that accepts a String as a parameter and returns that String with each pair of adjacent letters reversed. If the String has an odd number of letters, the last letter is unchanged. For example, the call swapPairs("example") should return "xemalpe" and the call swapPairs("hello there") should return "ehll ohtree".

```
public static String swapPairs(String s) {
    String t="";
    if(s.length()%2==0) {
        for (int i=0;i<s.length()/2;i++) {
            t+=s.charAt(2*i+1)+s.charAt(2*i);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i=0;i<s.length()/2;i++) {
            t+=s.charAt(2*i+1)+s.charAt(2*i);
         }
        t+=s.charAt(s.length()-1);
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: And what happens instead?

Comment: You could pull the `for` loop outside the `if` statement, it's the same in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String#charAt` returns a `char`. Adding two `char`s will result in another char (because `char` is a numeric type), not in a `String` as you seem to expect. The compiler should give you an error message in that direction.

You could use `String#substring` instead.

Comment: Or use `charAt()` with `StringBuilder`'s `append()`

Comment: That would probably be much more efficient :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use only 1 for cycles like:

```
public static String swapPairs(String s) {
    StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i += 2) {
        t.append(s.charAt(i + 1));
        t.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
    if(s.length() % 2 == 1) { //appending the last character if needed
        t.append(s.charAt(s.length() - 1));
    }
    return t.toString();
}
```

Also using StringBuilder is a nice idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just amend your method to use a `StringBuilder` instead and change it something like:

```
sb.append(s.charAt((2 * i) + 1)).append(s.charAt(2 * i));
```